# FOP fails to load image from url

Tags: java, xslt, apache-fop

I have a web api which returns an image. I am trying to integrate this to my FO template.

```
<fo:block font-weight="normal" text-align="left">
     <fo:external-graphic src="url({$URL})">
     </fo:external-graphic>
</fo:block>
```

where $URL is "http://{servername}/images/{id}".

I am getting the following error:

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error Type Exception Report
>
> Message Servlet execution threw an exception
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
>   prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   Root Cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/sun/media/jai/codec/FileCacheSeekableStream

I am able to access the image directly using http://{servername}/images/{id} url so the url is correct.

Comment: The important line is the last one: you are missing the JAI (Java Advanced Imaging) jar. You have to download it and put (or link) it in the `lib` folder.

Comment: Thanks, just posted the root cause of the problem.

Comment: From others question also unaswered it looks like there is a problem with JAI installation and JDK/JRE folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause was FOP was not able to load PNG image for PDF file. It worked fine with JPEG/BMP/GIF.

https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.0/graphics.html

Comment: It's not what the documentation says: _"PNG images are supported both through an Image I/O codec (ImageLoaderImageIO) and through native support. FOP native support is possible with PDF and PS output, and can be enabled either through an internal codec (ImageLoaderPNG) or by directly handling undecoded images (ImageLoaderRawPNG). More information is available in the wiki page. Transparency is supported but not guaranteed to work with every output format."_